# Loading a local page into Firefox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

For loading a local file into Firefox I have noticed that...

```
location.href = "./relative/path/file.htm";  //this works
location.href = "http://localhost/path/file.htm";   //this works
location.href = "file:///c:/absolute/path/file.htm"; //doesnt work (also doesnt work if remove the "file:///" bit)
```

I would like to get the last example to work. Is there some about.config setting I can add to allow this or maybe a "netscape.security.PrivilegeManager..." statement?

(This is for a special Firefox profile and not for general use so the insecurity issues are not relevant).
Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using the file:/// syntax?

Comment: @BeRecursive. I meant that if I do: "file://c:/absolute/path/file.htm" it doesnt work either.

Comment: Is the page that is calling this code on http?

Comment: Shouldn't the path be using \ instead of /?

Comment: @epascarello, yes the page running the javascript is also a local page (with address: localhost/...)

Comment: @epascarello, I also tried: file:///c:\\absolute\\path... but this didnt work either.

Answer (score 1):

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work#Firefox_1.5.2C_SeaMonkey_1.0_and_newer answers this

Answer (score 0):

when using "file:///" you need to use backslashes ( windows ) in other words you need to type
the physical address of the file as it accessed from file explorer ( windows )

dont forget escape with "\\".

example:

```
    var url = "file:///c:\\myDir\\1.html";
```